# Redirect audio output to hdmi connector

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio, hdmi, mfi

I have connected a MFI device with my iPhone 5 and a bluetooth device is also connected to that device.  Problem is audio is redirected to bluetooth and problem occurs only with HDMI connector, old 30-pin connector doesn't have such issue.

Can anyone help to how to redirect audio to HDMI connector only?

```
    UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;

    AudioSessionSetProperty (
                             kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker,

                             sizeof (doChangeDefaultRoute),

                             &doChangeDefaultRoute

                             );
```

I have used above statement to set default audio output route, but i think this is not enough, because it is not working with correct behaviour.

Thanks